# Omnifaces CombinedResourceHandler — Is there a way to exclude certain pages?

Tags: jsf-2.2, omnifaces, combinedresourcehandler

I'm using the `CombinedResourceHandler` of Omnifaces for many years now. For the first time I need to exclude some pages from combining resources.
Is this even possible? 
 I found only a way to exclude resources from combining or get suppressed and removed. But this is not enough for my purpose. 
 Thanks

Comment: Really, nobody has encountered this problem before? Even BalusC (the JSF God) has no answer for this?

Comment: Or maybe, does anyone know how to remove completely all the combined resources just for specific pages? The purpose behind my question is that I want to generate amp (Accelerated Mobile Pages) with JSF. And the combined resources is a big obstacle.